# React hook causing rerendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jwt

I have a hook that reads a token from local storage and decodes user claims from the token.

```js
export const useActiveUser = (): { user: IUserTokenClaims | null } => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserTokenClaims | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (!token) setUser(null);
        else {
            const claims = jwt.decode(token) as IUserTokenClaims;
            if (!claims.id || !claims.displayName || !claims.role) setUser(null);
            else {
                setUser({
                    id: claims.id,
                    displayName: claims.displayName,
                    role: claims.role
                });
            }
        }

    }, []);

    return {  user };
};
```

If I then use the hook in a component like so...

```js
export const SomeComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const { user } = useActiveUser();

    console.log(user)

    if (user) {/* Render stuff if user is logged in */}
    else {/* Render stuff if user is not logged in */}
}
```

The log statement would print `null` and on the second render it will log out the user claims.

Why does it render twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in your `useActiveUser` hook:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserTokenClaims | null>(null);
```

sets the initial value of `user` to `null`, and you only set `user` to another value in the `useEffect` hook which runs on (after) mount (the initial render). Thus on the first render `user` is `null`. You can either deal with this or make a few modifications to your code to avoid this.

Generally to avoid strange renders, you can add a `isLoading` state value, however, that approach is best suited for state values that must be set asynchronously (e.g. from calling an API). In this case you can just set the initial value of `user` to the calculated value right away (so no need for `isLoading`).

For example, calculating the value of `user` before setting up the `user` state value and using the `useMemo` hook:

```js
export const useActiveUser = (): { user: IUserTokenClaims | null } => {
    const user = useMemo(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (!token) {
            return null;
        } else {
            const claims = jwt.decode(token) as IUserTokenClaims;
            if (!claims.id || !claims.displayName || !claims.role) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return {
                    id: claims.id,
                    displayName: claims.displayName,
                    role: claims.role
                };
            }
        }
    }, []);

    return { user };
};
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I didnt realize the default value caused an initial render.  Your solution works.  I removed the call to `setState` all together now and return userData.

Comment: Until using the solution you provided, I was using a `isLoading` in my implementation as you mentioned.  It just seemed... wrong lol. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. The `isLoading` approach is generally only suited for state values that need to be set asynchronously (e.g. calling an API), but here we can calculate synchronously, so no need!

Answer (score 1):

It rerenders twice because you are calling the `setUser` inside a `useEffect` hook, which is the same as the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method on class components.

1. First render
2. `user` value is `null`
3. Component mounted, `useEffect` kicked in.
4. Parsing the user from localstorage
5. Set the parsed user
6. Trigger the second rerender